# How to queue data before ES

Tags: elasticsearch, queue, logstash

I have big netflow data(about 10 million logs/sec) ingest into ES through logstash, but I am afraid that ES is too late to write data in its database(how can I check if there has some data lost?).
Therefore, I think I should insert a software to queue the data before sending it to ES to prevent dropping data.
Is there any suggest software or any idea?
I have tried Kafka, but it seems a little difficult.
My OS is windows.

this is my structure:

[image]
thank you very much!

Comment: Logstash has a [persistent queue](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.1/persistent-queues.html)

Comment: so, I don't have to worry about data lost!?

Comment: when will the data be delete of the persistent queue? After processing successfully? or never be delete?

Comment: You should read that link :-)